How to set up Nginx and Docker to allow Nextjs to communicate with a Nestjs backend
I have a full set up that works well in development but not in production due to SSL certificate.

I have a nextjs frontend
I have a nestjs backend
And around this I have Docker-compose, Nginx and let's encrypt everything hosted on a
VPS.

With the example below, you can see that on the server side of Nextjs, I can't reach my backend using /api directly but need to prefix by http://nginx/api.
This work well in development on localhost but of course, in production http://nginx in not recognized with the certificate.
Do you know how I can improve my configuration ? Either by editing my nginx conf to allow this kind of prefix, or on the nextjs side by avoiding this prefix.
my fetch from nextjs component
export default async function ServerHelloPage() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('http://nginx/api/');
    const data = await res.text();
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(data);
    }
    return <h1 className='text-3xl font-bold'>{data}</h1>;
  } catch (error) {
    return <h1 className='text-3xl font-bold'>Error</h1>;
  }
}


my nginx conf
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}


http {

    sendfile on;
    upstream client {
        server client:3000;
    }
    upstream api {
        server api:3001;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name <my-domain>.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name <my-domain>.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my-domain>/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my-domain>/privkey.pem;


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://client;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;




            proxy_cookie_path / "/; HTTPOnly; Secure";
        }
        location /api {
          # Strips '/api' from the URI before passing it to the backend


            rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://api/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;


        }

    }
}

my docker-compose conf
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.production
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    networks:
      - web

  client:
    container_name: client
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.production
    restart: always
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

    networks:
      - web

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - api
      - client
    networks:
      - web
networks:
  web:
    driver: bridge

Thanks
